# Add binary or json animation to wordpress site

Tags: json

I just created an animation with *[RIVE](https://rive.app/explore/popular/trending/all)*. There are options to export the animation as binary or json file.

Is it someway possible to include my animation into my wordpress site?

Comment: How would you include this in a static HTML page? animations aren't normally binary/JSON, they're CSS animations, or videos, or they work with some sort of javascript library. Also, when you say include into your WP site, do you mean as a part of your theme? Or something else? It's unclear

Comment: Looks like you would need to setup/install one of the JS runtimes, https://rive.app/runtimes.  Voting this as off-topic as it really has little to do with WordPress and more about RIVE.